# SQL join and multiply

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm pretty new to SQL, and all of my background is in procedural languages. I'm having quite a bit of difficulty, and until now have been able to research the answers to all of my questions.

I have two tables, structured like so:

dbo.SERVICE - A list of all service orders/maintenance calls ever

```
SERVICE_ORDER_NO | PART_NO | QUANTITY | PART_DESC | CREATED_DT | CHANGED_DT
```

dbo.PART - A list of all parts in the machine being serviced

```
PART_NO | COST
```

I would like to get a list of the parts used in a given time frame, including the total quantity and total cost, and sort by quantity. So far I have been able to get the parts used and the quantity appropriately, using the following query (dates have been hardcoded for simplicity):

```
SELECT SERV.PART_NO, SUM(SERV.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY
FROM dbo.SERVICE SERV
WHERE SERV.CREATED_DT >= '01/01/2012'  AND SERV.CREATED_DT < '02/01/2012'
GROUP BY SERV.PART_NO
ORDER BY QUANTITY DESC
```

I'm having trouble getting the total cost though. I tried this:

```
SELECT SERV.PART_NO, SUM(SERV.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY, SUM(SERV.QUANTITY * PART.COST) AS COST
FROM dbo.SERVICE SERV
INNER JOIN dbo.PART PART
ON PART.PART_NO = SERV.PART_NO
WHERE SERV.CREATED_DT >= '01/01/2012'  AND SERV.CREATED_DT < '02/01/2012'
GROUP BY SERV.PART_NO
ORDER BY QUANTITY DESC
```

However, the numbers are wrong (quantities are much too high), and I get about 1600 rows when my previous query gave me 1900. I'm assuming there's something wrong with my JOIN statement, but I don't know what it is. Can anyone give me a working query, or point me to a good reference for my problem?

Any direction to good general SQL help repositories would be great too... I haven't really found any one place that is both comprehensive and easily understood.

PS - Is that fact that I call SUM() twice in that query going to slow my code down? I don't know how SQL works... is it smart enough to take the results from the QUANTITY column and multiply them, or no? If not, what is the syntax to run it more efficiently?

Comment: Then you have multiple costs for the same part, you need to choose one first, it can be the minimum, the maximum, the average....

Comment: It sounds like you need to fix the cost table, so you have time frames for each cost.  The part_no is not unique in this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said on a comment, you have multiple values of `COST` for each `PART_NO` on your table `PART`. For your join to work, you need to choose one cost:

```
SELECT SERV.PART_NO, SUM(SERV.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY, SUM(SERV.QUANTITY * PART.COST) AS COST
FROM dbo.SERVICE SERV
INNER JOIN (SELECT PART_NO, MIN(COST) AS COST 
            FROM dbo.PART 
            GROUP BY PART_NO) AS PART
ON PART.PART_NO = SERV.PART_NO
WHERE SERV.CREATED_DT >= '01/01/2012'  AND SERV.CREATED_DT < '02/01/2012'
GROUP BY SERV.PART_NO
ORDER BY QUANTITY DESC
```

I chose the minimum cost for each part, but you can change it to the maximum or average.

Comment: Max would most likly be the most current, but really the table design is the problem. You should be able to tell from the table what is the current price without aggregates. I would suggest adding begin and end dates and a trigger to populate the end date of any part with no enddate  when it is entered with a new price.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the table structure, just the data within. Thank you very much for your help, however.